# Is there a way of adding a single row from an SQL result Table temporarily?

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL Example:

```
WITH temp_roles as 
  (
    SELECT * FROM 
      ROLE_ WHERE NAME IN (                                                                                          
      'User','Owner','Portal Content Reviewer','Community Owner','Administrator'                 
      )   
  )
```

I am creating a temporary table in which I would like to add an additional row of values, just for this query, is there any way of doing it.

Note: 
I am using Oracle SQL. 
tnx :D

Comment: You could use a UNION and add the values explicitly

Comment: as example: `select object_name from all_objects
union all
select 'my_name' from  dual
union all
select 'my_name1' from dual`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a UNION you could add the values manually, i.e.:

```
WITH temp_roles 
  as (     
      SELECT *
        FROM role_
       WHERE name IN ('User', 'Owner', 'Portal Content Reviewer', 
                      'Community Owner', 'Administrator')
      UNION
      SELECT <values>
        FROM dual
     )
```

BTW, i'm not sure why you are using the `WITH` clause?